# AngularJS v1.5.5 Reset form not working for invalid input fields

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have the code below (or see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwstarikanos/utwf604r/10/)) and I try to reset form and clear all input fields too for each form.

With **AngularJS version 1.2.1** is working fine! but in my app I using version **1.5.5** because I have other libraries for separating the nested forms in `<md-tab>` tags using material framework who need this version.

The [problem](http://recordit.co/eUGzO5L3Ys) is when any field it's invalid then **reset** does not work as expected and these fields remain unchanged instead to be clear.

There is another way to clearing all fields (of nested form) when I click reset button ?

```js
angular.module("main", [])
  .controller("register", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      A: {},
      B: {}
    };

    $scope.reset = function(form) {
      form.$setPristine();
    };

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="main">
  <div ng-controller="register" class="form">

    <form name="form" novalidate role="form">

      <div class="form">


        <h1>TAB1 - Form A:</h1>
        <ng-form name="A">
          A1:
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.A.A1" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="15" />A2:
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.A.A2" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="15" />
          <button type="button" ng-disabled="A.$pristine" ng-click="reset(A); data.A=null;">Reset</button>
          <br/>
          <strong>A.$pristine =</strong> {{A.$pristine}}
          <strong>A.$valid =</strong> {{A.$valid}}
        </ng-form>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <br/>

      <div class="form">


        <h1>TAB2 - Form B:</h1>
        <ng-form name="B">
          B1:
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.B.B1" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="15" />B2
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.B.B2" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="15" />

          <button type="button" ng-disabled="B.$pristine" ng-click="reset(B); data.B=null;">Reset</button>
          <br/>
          <strong>B.$pristine =</strong> {{B.$pristine}}
          <strong>B.$valid =</strong> {{B.$valid}}
        </ng-form>
      </div>
    </form>

    <h1>data:</h1>
    <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle which reproduces the problem?

Comment: check this which uses AngularJs 1.4.8 and reset not working for invalid input fields: https://jsfiddle.net/kwstarikanos/utwf604r/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `ng-model` binds to the `A` and `B` objects by *reference* in $scope.data. If you remove the `$scope.data.A = null` from your `ng-click` and reset the object without creating a new one, it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/utwf604r/15/

```
$scope.reset = function (form)
{
  // don't change the reference to A
  // $scope.data.A = {} wont work!!
    angular.extend($scope.data, {A:{A1:'',A2:''}, B:{B1:'',B2:''}});
    form.$setPristine();
};
```

Comment: thanks, your changes really works but I'll try to convert as follow: when a user clicks on A form reset button, I want to reset only 'A form'. There is a way to get 'data.A' variable (or 'data.B' respectively) from 'form' argument inside the 'reset' function to avoid using switch - case ?

Comment: new update: https://jsfiddle.net/kwstarikanos/utwf604r/17/ (eventually I think that there is no way to avoid the use of switch)

Comment: You can key off the form name like so: https://jsfiddle.net/utwf604r/18/ or even simpler, pass in the model which needs to be reset explicitly as a second param: https://jsfiddle.net/utwf604r/19/